# Google apps script search sheet for value is not working like expected

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to search my google sheet for a value, the value that I am looking for is an ID for customers; 'SGK - xxx' is the format of the ID (xxx is a number).
I am currently using the following code:

```
var data = spr.getDataRange().getValues(); 
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){ 
    if(data[n][0].toString().match(CustomerNumber)==CustomerNumber){ 
      data[n][19] = emailCustomer

   var KlantNR = data[n][0];
   var Email = data[n][3];
   var Stad = data[n][10];          
   var Taalschool = data[n][11];    
   var Cursus = data[n][12];      
   var Weken = data[n][13];
   var Accommodatie1 = data[n][15];
   var TypeAccommodatie = data[n][16];
   var TypeKamer = data[n][17];
   var VertrekDatum1 = data[n][18];

    };
  }
  Logger.log(data)
  spr.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

For example: When I search on 'SGK - 4', this code returns 'SGK - 499'. How can I edit this code to return the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.match(CustomerNumber)
```

When I remove that line of code it works fine..